# Table - Live Search with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been working on a solution for a Live Search on my table of data.

When I search `Jim` it works as expected :-)

However, when I search `Carey`, no results appear. Why is this? :-(

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/L1d7naem/

```js
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

            if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
table, tr, td, th{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 2px;
}

table th{
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><th>Forename</th><th>Surname</th><th>Extension</th></tr>
<tr><td>Jim</td><td>Carey</td><td>1945</td></tr>
<tr><td>Michael</td><td>Johnson</td><td>1946</td></tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```

Comment: there's a plugin to do this, it also handles pagination and sorting too: https://datatables.net/, but to answer your question, you are only comparing against the first td: `$row.find("td:first").text()`

Comment: @Pete Many thanks for this. I'm looking into that plugin. How do I resolve my current code to search the other td's? :)

Comment: I would do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/L1d7naem/14/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour you want can be achieved with the following corrections in the each loop (also note the `< 0` in the condition...):

```
var id = $.map($row.find('td'), function(element) {
    return $(element).text()
}).join(' ');

if (id.indexOf(value) < 0) {
    $row.hide();
} else {
    $row.show();
}
```

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle? Can you explain where this should go?

Comment: Sure: http://jsfiddle.net/d04yfx8d/. I append all string values of the tds and apply the filter on it.

Comment: Nice solution : )

Comment: Wow - this is a brilliant solution!!

Answer (score 6):

Its because of the following line:

```
var id = $row.find("td:first").text();
```

You are working on the first column of table only and "Carey" is in second column of table

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You have to iterate through all columns and once you find any match just escape the loop using the `return false;` within `each()` function. Also, [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns -1 if string is not found.

```js
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            $row.find("td").each(function(){
              var id = $(this).text();
              if (id.indexOf(value) < 0) {
                $row.hide();
              }
              else {
                $row.show();
                return false;
              }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```css
table, tr, td, th{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 2px;
}

table th{
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><th>Forename</th><th>Surname</th><th>Extension</th></tr>
<tr><td>Jim</td><td>Carey</td><td>1945</td></tr>
<tr><td>Michael</td><td>Johnson</td><td>1946</td></tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
      $("#search").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

    $("table tr").each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {

            $row = $(this);

            var id = $.map($row.find('td'), function(element) {
    return $(element).text()
}).join(' ');





            if (id.indexOf(value) <0) {
                $row.hide();
            }
            else {
                $row.show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lyxex4tp/

Comment: It's nearly perfect :-D Can you explain why when I type `19` nothing appears? I was expecting both rows to still display. Help? :)

Comment: Because the following code do not consider third td into the searching, that's why on typing 19 nothing happens

Comment: This seems to resolve it http://jsfiddle.net/L1d7naem/12/ whoever the master is behind this :-D

Comment: You're the master :-D Thank you, Jekin!! :)

Comment: With my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39224667/2940802 you can filter for all columns, no matter how many they are...

Comment: kindly accept answer if you thinks its helpful to you :D

Comment: I will do - 20 seconds to go :-)

Comment: @JekinKalariya you are master :)

Comment: @JekinKalariya Out of interest. When I search `Jim Carey` it doesn't show anything : http://jsfiddle.net/Lbod9uj1. Why is this?

Comment: @MayankPandey have a look to my solution. It solves your last problem...

Comment: José Antonio Postigo is very right   http://jsfiddle.net/qxks62x9/   this is final one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
var value = $(this).val();

$("table td").each(function() {
    if(value.match($(this).text)) {
        console.log($(this).text());
    }

    else {
        $("table").hide();
    }
});
});
```

Try matching with all the td elements.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works,

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
var value = $(this).val();

$("table tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index !== 0) {
        var id = $(this).children().text()
        if (id.indexOf(value) < 0) {
           $(this).hide();
        }else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    }
 });
});
```

Here is the working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/44Lux7ze/